# Upgrade paradox? Gold storage and Town Hall

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans,

The following seems to be presenting a paradox:

- I can't upgrade my Level 5 Town Hall until I upgrade my level 9 Gold Storage
- Yet conversely I can't upgrade my gold storage while I upgrade my town hall!

Is this working as intended? I feel like I am missing something here...

Comment: is this Clash of Clans? if so what is the level of your Town Hall/Storage and how many do you have

Comment: What game is this? You need to explain a lot more if you want some assistance with this issue

Comment: That has never happened

Comment: My hall is level 5 and my gold storage is level 9, I have enough gems to do either upgrade yet have ran into a catch 22, can't do one without doing the other first.  And yes, coc

Comment: @WarrenGilBouchard you say **your gold *storage***, does this mean you only have one, at Town Hall Level 5 you can build a second, see the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Storage)

Comment: You can upgrade your second 1

Comment: ok, now it makes more sense with the appropriate tags

Comment: Reworded the OP's question to be answered and not draw ire

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have BOTH storages? You should only be having this problem if you only have one storage

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is first check to see if you have the max amount of storage for your respective level for you this should be two.

Then check to see if they are both at the max level (9). Then try to fill them.